# Does the Duck Journal still count Killstreaks?

Tags: team-fortress-2

The [Duck Journal](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Duck_Journal) used to count killstreaks (as well as ducks). Is this still the case? I want to buy it for fun but I'm worried it won't count the killstreak. I've checked everywhere I can think of, does anyone know if the Duck Journal still counts killstreaks?

Comment: Is the question "Does "Duck Journal still add to my kill-streak count?" or what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Ducks were added as part of the Dec 2014 - Jan 2015 "*End of the Line*" Event.

[image: End of the Line Poster]

The Duck Journal itself only counts killstreaks during special events known as a 'Duck Journal Events':

> This item has several features, including increasing the drop rate for ducks and displaying a counter labeled Duckstreaks during a Duck Journal event".
>   <sub>[TF2 Wiki: Duck Journal](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Duck_Journal)</sub>

Unfortunately, from January 5th & 7th 2015, the Duck Journal Event has ended, meaning that ducks no longer drop, and kills do not count towards a Duckstreak:

> **January 5, 2015 Patch**
>   [Undocumented] Ducks no longer drop after a player is killed.
>   **January 7, 2015 Patch**
>   [Undocumented] Removed Duck Journal event from the main menu.
>   [Undocumented] Removed the Duck Journal from the Mann Co. Store.
>   <sub>[TF2 Wiki: Duck Journal](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Duck_Journal)</sub>

However, the Duck Journal is not *completely* useless. It can still be used as a Noisemaker:

> ...using an equipped Duck Journal with the action item button will cause one of several Duck Collectors Bumper Car game quack sounds to play. This action is available at any time, independent of events, with a cool down period between quacks.
>   <sub>[TF2 Wiki: Duck Journal](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Duck_Journal)</sub>

There are also some that believe another Duck-related event may occur in the future.*

<sub>* Such an event would be quite specquackular!</sub>